# Tables and columns used in ASE SYBASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jquery-selectors, sybase

Good Morning!

I need a way to know the name of the tables and columns of this tables that are using (select, insert, update, delete) by stored procedures and SQL querys in ASE SYBASE or SQL SERVER database

I need the list of tables and columns that really we are using right now

Thanks,

Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get all the tables and columns from a server you can do it this way.

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT
    *
FROM ?.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @Query
```